# how to add ngClass condition inside a component which is used in another component

Tags: angular

im new in angular i have a grid which has a detail view im using Kendo,when I click on the row the detail which is in another component will be binded:

```
 <div *kendoGridDetailTemplate="let dataSource">
 <category-details [ngClass]="{'positive':dataSource.comment=='VPN'}"></app-category-details> 
</div>
```

one them items of my dataSource is a comment  when the comment is VPN I want to change the background color using the CSS positive:

```
 .positive {
    background-color: green;
}
```

the above code does not work and also does not give me any error, generally adding condition like this should work if inside another component I add a condition!?any help will be appreacited

Comment: your code looks fine. Make sure that the `category-details` component does not override the `background-color` property.

Comment: let me clarify what "does not work mean". do you see the `positive` class in the markup?

Comment: @IAfanasov good question gona check it

Comment: @hlfrmn you mean if there is any class which overrides?

Comment: your code looks fine try to debug, use `{{dataSource.comment}}` in html to check if dataSource.comment is 'VPN' , also use if `dataSource.comment === 'VPN'` is getting true

Answer (score 0):

Define your `.positive` class in global css file.

your `ngClass` would like this:

```
[ngClass]="dataSource.comment=='VPN' ? 'positive':''"
```

Comment: you mean app.component.css?

Comment: you can add it to styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you just need to set `ViewEncapsulation.None` for `category-details` component

```
@Component({
...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
...
```

Comment: class is not added and adding what you said has not change the result yet

Comment: the possible scope of error shrank (: it is either condition `dataSource.comment=='VPN'` return `false` either someone else overrides `background-color` (: